# When using makefile, linux header is found, but when functions from the header are called, it says they are implicitly declared

Tags: c, linux, makefile, kernel

I'm writing a kernel module and I've begun to look into sockets. I've been able to include other linux headers, use their functions, and the makefile will be fine. When I include linux/socket.h, the compiler is able to find the file, but if I call `socket()` or `connect()` or such, it says they are implicitly declared. How would I be able to fix this?

I've used cat to look into the file to make sure it's correct, which it is. I've tried just hardcoding the location

/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-17-generic/linux/socket.h

I've also tried using linux-headers-4.18.0-17's socket.h but that also doesn't work.

one of the errors: 
error: implicit declaration of function 'socket'; did you mean 'sget'? [-Werror=implicit-function--declaration]

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not `socket()`, it's `sys_socket()` and you also need the header file containing the system calls. That one only contains structs and constants. The header file with the function itself is `linux/syscalls.h`.

Comment: I believe I've already included the system calls header file. So I need to track down sys_socket.h file?

Comment: @Icarus_Incarnate: Found the header for you.

Comment: +1

so I poked around for a bit and found it as __sys_socket, so thanks for the answer